# iOS Not show admob interstitial

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

iOS not show admin interstitial ID ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910 (Google Example) Show test admob interstitial but ID me ca-app-pub-8084139945896039/3483224303 not show ???

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GADInterstitial.h"

@interface ViewController ()<GADInterstitialDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-8084139945896039/3483224303";
    self.interstitial.delegate = self;
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    // Assumes an image named "SplashImage" exists.
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"SplashImage"]];
    self.imageView.frame = self.view.frame;
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
}
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    NSLog(@"Method 3");
}
- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"Error");
}

- (void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"Method 3");

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you created a Banner ad unit, instead of an Interstitial ad unit at admob.com?

Try creating a new one.